# Change the contents of a UITableView via a swipe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, gesture

Im currently using a UITableView like any other, and I am researching into the ability to perform a swipe gesture on the screen, which will then shift the contents of the visible table over to display new content

for example: swiping right-to-left on the screen would change (via animation) the contents within each of the cells on screen to show new data.

What I can do is detect a swipe on the cells, or perhaps on the UITableViewController, but what I dont know how to do two fold:

1) Change data in all cells (could you have a set of hidden views within a custom table cell that animate in and out of each cell per swipe?)

2) How can you do this to all cells?

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a custom table cell which had 3 UIViews inside it, only one of which was visible. Then I iterated over each cell on screen, and animated in and out the appropriate UIView from left to right (or the other way around).

I did not, however, end up using a swipe gesture, too fiddly...

Answer (score 1):

Well you can detect touches providing the following implementation:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Then to reload you cells, Update your DataSource Array and call

> [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: do you want to animate each cell or the whole TableView?

if you want to animate the whole table view then you can put this method in the UIView animation block.....